# How to use the CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY function

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

In cell `A1` we have this:

```
=CUBEMEMBER("OurCube","TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day].MEMBERS,1).item(0)","TargetMember")
```

It works fine and returns a single member that is yesterday.

In `A2` we have a formula that is attempting to return the actual date - so I thought the `CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY` function would work:

```
=CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY("OurCube",A1,"member_caption")
```

The above returns `#N/A`

Comment: Is this a pure SSAS cube or a PowerPivot model?

Comment: @KyleHale it is an `SSAS` cube into `Excel-2010` so using `MDX` rather than `DAX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what CUBEMEMBERPRPERTY does but apparently it doesn't mean what you think it means!
If you need to get a certain property of a field according to another field, this is the way to do it:
Let's say, I wanted the Financial Year's month name (FY Month Name) based on a certain date key (I live in Australia, the financial year finishes at June):

```
=CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel", "EXISTS([Dim Period].[FY Month Name].Children, [Dim Period].[Datekey].[20160731])")
```

And if the value of "20160731" has been in a certain cell, it would go like this:

```
=CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel", "EXISTS([Dim Period].[FY Month Name].Children, [Dim Period].[Datekey].["&A8&"])")
```

Both would give me the correct answer: 01 - July

And I would like to thank the following posts for their help:
https://wessexbi.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/a-cubememberproperty-equivalent-with-powerpivot/

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/power-bi/730287-function-cubememberproperty-always-return-n.html